# In Java, can I have a parent class implement a method that uses a variable from a subclass?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I'm looking to simplify some methods that are shared across all of my subclasses, in which case there's 25+. I currently use an interface to implement

```
public int getRow() {
    return row;
}
public boolean getCondition() {
    return condition;
}
```

and a few more that are similar in nature (getters/setters)

Is it possible to define a method in the parent class body that uses the subclass variable and avoid having these generic getters and setters in the subclass?

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a couple of examples?

Comment: Why don't you declare the field in the parent?

Comment: @AliasCartellano this is not possible. You can put methods in interfaces. You can't put fields in there, though. Hence, non-starter.

Comment: If the goal is just to avoid having to write out all the getters on the subclasses, have you looked at using Lombok to generate them for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, for obvious reasons: There is no guarantee that *every* subclass actually has that variable, therefore it is not possible to refer to it short of reaching for obviously silly ideas such as reflection.

However, if you feel that every subclass of this class really would have these 2 fields, then, shouldn't those fields just be part of the parent class instead? If you have:

```java
public abstract class SpreadsheetRowMarker {}

public final class InvoiceRowMarker extends SpreadsheetRowMarker {
  private final int row;

  public InvoiceRowMarker(int row) {
    this.row = row;
  }

  public int getRow() {
    return row;
  }
}

// another 24 classes a lot like InvoiceRowMarker
```

and not just that, but it is effectively ingrained in the very nature of whatever `SpreadsheetRowMarker` is attempting to represent that **ALL** imaginable subclasses of it would look like that, then the above seems weird. If it's functionality that is intrinsically bundled up with SpreadsheetRowMarker itself, just make it part of that:

```
public abstract class SpreadsheetRowMarker {
  private final int row;

  public SpreadsheetRowMarker(int row) {
    this.row = row;
  }

  public int getRow() {
    return row;
  }
}

public final class InvoiceRowMarker extends SpreadsheetRowMarker {
  public InvoiceRowMarker(int row) {
    super(row);
  }
}

// and 24 more such classes
```

unfortunately you can't get rid of those constructors, but presumably you already had 24 constructors that took in a `row` variable. The above means `getRow()` is now centrally placed, *and* that you can now invoke it on anything as long as you know it is a `SpreadsheetRowMarker` (vs knowing it's any one of its many subclasses).

If you have 25 types that all extend SpreadsheetRowMarker but you CAN imagine subtypes that don't have it, then consider making another class to 'sit in between' (if you have `class F extends A {}` right now, make a new `abstract class B extends A {}` and then have your 25 current classes with `getRow` extend B instead. Put the `getRow` stuff in B.